Are LLMs active when no prompts are sent to them?
Does anyone know if LLMs consume electricity / processing when idle? By idle I mean when no prompts are sent to them, with the server on which they are operated being online.
What I think I know of these models and of AI models in general right now is that they consume processing while training and testing, but once the training is done, they only exist in the storage as an assembly of bits, waiting for the users to "run" them on new data.


Does anyone know if LLMs consume electricity / processing when idle?

A bit of electricity to maintain the RAM or VRAM the LLM is stored on, as LLMs typically aren't loaded from disk for each inference.
